# In Qt, Is there a signal like "singleClicked"?

Tags: qt, qt4

In Qt view's there is a signal called doubleClicked, that I have been using.

Is there a singleClicked or something like that?

Comment: @cbamber85 Have a look at [Model/View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicked() ? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qabstractitemview.html#clicked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called `clicked`.

If that doesn't work, try [`contentsMousePressEvent`](http://qt-x11-free.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.3.8really3.3.7/classQScrollView_57d80d7dbca89b1614f8f046f9dc29e4.html#57d80d7dbca89b1614f8f046f9dc29e4).